# How to avoid MissingMethodException when using Xamarin Google Play Services?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use the Google Play Services component from Xamarin but it seems that the methods in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv can not be found at runtime when using it.

Here are my usings:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Location;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
```

Here is an example of failing code:

```
request = new LocationRequest();
request.SetNumUpdates(1);
```

It results in this exeption (when calling SetNumUpdates):

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod'.

This code:

```
request = new LocationRequest();
 client = new GoogleApiClientBuilder(this).AddApi(LocationServices.API).AddConnectionCallbacks(this).AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this).Build();
```

results in the following exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance

How do I make sure the methods in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv can be found? It is strange because Mono.Android is included and intellisense is able to find these methods. I can find them myself so what is the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Does your emulator/device have Google Play Services installed on it?

If you're using a real device google play services are automatically installed.

If you're using an android emulator from the android sdk you must create an emulator from a google API image

[image]

Comment: I use a real device. So it should just work. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: i've found something on forums: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45126/google-play-services-location-api-fails

Comment: Thanks but this issue is different: in link you added, "CallObjectMethod" is throwing an exception. My situation is different: "CallObjectMethod" can not be found at all at runtime.